# Is mass variance independent of redshift in Press-Schechter formalism?

Tags: cosmology

The Press & Schechter mass function could be written as
$$
n(M,t)dM=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}~~\dfrac{\rho_{\textrm{mean}}}{M^2}\dfrac{\delta_c}{\sigma}\exp\left(-\dfrac{\delta_c^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\left|\dfrac{d\ln\sigma}{d\ln M}\right|dM,
$$
which describes a number density of collapsed objects with masses in the range between $M$ and $M+dM$. I read Mo, Frank van den Bosch and Simon White's book, 'Galaxy Formation and evolution' and find the words say that

> Note that time enters Eq. (7.45) only through δ c(t), and that mass enters through σ (M) and its derivative.

Eq. (7.45) is the equation above. It makes sence that the overdensity field $\delta(x,t)$ evolves over time and i'm confused about Why $\sigma(M)$ is independent of time?

The definition of $\sigma^2(M)$ is given by
$$
\sigma^2(M)=\langle \delta^2(x;R)\rangle=\dfrac{V_k}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\infty P(k)W^2(kR)k^2dk,
$$
where $ \delta^2(x;R)$ means the density field is smoothed by a sphere with a radius $R$ and the $W(kR)$ is a corresponded window function which is given as
$$
W(kR)=3\dfrac{\sin(kR)-kR\cos(kR)}{(kR)^2}.
$$
and we assume the initial spectrum of the density fluctuations is a power law:
$P(k)\propto k^n.$

Now if we choose the comoving coordinates, the length must be multiplied with a scale factor $a(t)$:
$$
k=\dfrac{2\pi n_k}{\lambda a(t)},~~V_k=a(t)^3V_k^\prime
$$
and
$$
R=a(t)R^\prime.
$$

Eventually we found that $a(t)$ is inevitablly involved in $\sigma(M)$ if $n\neq 0$. As the book says $\sigma(M)$ seems independent of time and I wonder whether something wrong is in my calculations.

I'll appreciate it if someone could answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to linear-order cosmological perturbation theory, density contrasts $\delta\equiv(\rho-\bar\rho)/\bar\rho$ grow proportionally with some growth function $D(a)$. For example, during matter domination, $D(a)\propto a$. The power spectrum accordingly grows as $P\propto D(a)^2$, and the rms variance grows as $\sigma\propto D(a)$.

Meanwhile, according to the spherical collapse model, the critical linear density contrast for collapse is some number $\delta_\mathrm{c}(a)$. For example, $\delta_\mathrm{c}=1.686$ during matter domination, but it is larger during the radiation epoch and is slightly smaller today due to dark energy.

So both $\sigma$ and $\delta_\mathrm{c}$ depend on time.
However, since the Press-Schechter formalism only cares about the ratio $\delta_\mathrm{c}/\sigma$, you can equivalently think of $\sigma$ being constant while absorbing the growth function $D$ into the definition of $\delta_\mathrm{c}$, so that $\delta_\mathrm{c}\propto 1/D(a)$. This is what your source is doing. It might seem like an arbitrary choice, but it can be convenient, particularly when making more intricate calculations, like using conditional mass functions to study assembly histories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps a lot. But why do people not use $\dfrac{\delta_c}{\sigma D(a)^2}$? It seems more reasonable since $\delta(x,t)=\delta_0(x)D(a)$ and the collapsed regions follow $\delta(x,t)>\delta_c$. Thus we get $\delta_c(t)=\delta_c/D(a)$. $\sigma$ follows the growth of the power spectrum and grows as $\sigma\propto D(a)$.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding. But on why the square of the growth function would be inappropriate: the more physically faithful picture is that $\sigma\propto D$ and that $\delta_\mathrm{c}\simeq 1.686$ does not incorporate the growth function at all. It can be useful to redefine the quantities to say instead that $\delta_\mathrm{c}\propto 1/D$ and that $\sigma$ is constant. But it would be incorrect to include the growth function scaling in both $\sigma$ and $\delta_\mathrm{c}$.

Comment: If you're just wondering why not leave the growth function out of the definitions of both $\sigma$ and $\delta_\mathrm{c}$, that is also a common convention, which leaves you with factors $\frac{\delta_\mathrm{c}}{\sigma D(a)}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. I appreciate it for your kind answer.